# Document Ready Function - Add submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is the code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = new Array();
        data['result'] = '5';
        data['x_invoice'] = '123456';
        data['x_iduser'] = '23456';
        data['x_description'] = 'Desbloquear iPhone 6 Plus';
        data['x_document'] = '45767';
        data['x_amount'] = '24690.00';
                    data['x_amount_usd'] = '35.93';
                data['x_parent_invoice'] = '';
        data['x_control'] = 'dfhdfghfdgsdf';
        console.log(data);
        $.global.redirect_with_post('https://somedomain.com', data);
    });
</script>
```

This code auto redirect on page load so I stopped the JavaScript to change parameters and now I am stuck because I need to submit it with a submit button

Is this possible?

Tried like this with no luck

```
<input type="submit" onclick="function">
```

Adding this code after the javascript

Comment: You have to create a named function instead of using `$(document).ready`, and put that function's name in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Oh wait. You want to perform the operation when JavaScript is off?

Comment: Javascript was off just to stop it but now is on awaiting the redirect of this code

Answer (score 1):

A quick comment - a shorter syntax instead of `data = new Array()` would be

```
var data = {
   result    : 5,
   x_invoice : '123456',
   x_iduser  : '23456'
   // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickedInput(){
        var data = new Array();
        data['result'] = '5';
        data['x_invoice'] = '123456';
        data['x_iduser'] = '23456';
        data['x_description'] = 'Desbloquear iPhone 6 Plus';
        data['x_document'] = '45767';
        data['x_amount'] = '24690.00';
                    data['x_amount_usd'] = '35.93';
                data['x_parent_invoice'] = '';
        data['x_control'] = 'dfhdfghfdgsdf';
        console.log(data);
        $.global.redirect_with_post('https://somedomain.com', data);
    };
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="clickedInput()"> <!-- See changed type -->
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onSubmit() {
          var data = new Array();
            data['result'] = '5';
            data['x_invoice'] = '123456';
            data['x_iduser'] = '23456';
            data['x_description'] = 'Desbloquear iPhone 6 Plus';
            data['x_document'] = '45767';
            data['x_amount'] = '24690.00';
                        data['x_amount_usd'] = '35.93';
                    data['x_parent_invoice'] = '';
            data['x_control'] = 'dfhdfghfdgsdf';
            console.log(data);
            $.global.redirect_with_post('https://somedomain.com', data);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
          var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
          form.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);
        });
</script>
```